# Built in remote contacts system on Outlook w/o Exchange?

Tags: outlook, remote, synchronization, contacts

I want to know if there is any native way (no third party plugins required) to get the contacts book on Outlook fetch some contacts from a remote location.

Scenario is:

- Several Windows PCs running Outlook 2013 with one POP3 email account per PC, with local pst files.
- All PCs are on the same network - so if a solution involves a network shared folder, it's still valid.
- Network contains some Linux and Windows Server servers, if needed for some kind of service deploying.

The best solution would be one which allows the users to have their own local address book, but also see contacts from that remote address book and periodically download new contacts added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure an LDAP directory as address book in Account Settings -> Address Books.

This can be an Active Directory from a Windows Domain, OpenLDAP, other LDAP services should work as well.

The user will still be able to store local contacts.